# Do we need Google Fit App for Google Fit API?

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I made small test app which shows daily steps using Google Fit API. During testing, I was not getting any steps count. But later I realised that my Samsung S5 doesn't come's with Google Fit app so I downloaded it and after feeding some data then I tested my app again and Now I can see my steps count on my test app.

So Does this means that in order to use Google Fit API all my app users must have installed Google Fit App?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the Google Fit app does automatically collect some information for you (such as steps, current activity) throughout the day, **it should not be assumed that it is installed**. In fact, for any kind of data you wish to show in your app using the Google Fit API, you should use the [Recording API](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/record) to record the data yourself.

In the background, the Google Fit API will dedup any identical requests across multiple apps (i.e., if your app and the Google Fit app are both installed and both record steps, it won't cost double the battery life).

Comment: If I just try fetching data using the history API without google fit being installed would that give me data buckets? say If I try pulling even the current day's step count value using the history API.

Comment: @AnirudhGanesh - if *nothing* is collecting data and inserting it into Google Fit, then you'll get no data back. Something still needs to be adding data in for you to read data out - the point is that it doesn't have to be the Google Fit app that is adding in that data (it could just as easily be Strava, Withings, etc. that integrate with Google Fit).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do use RecordingAPI and according to the documentation that you've mentioned, Fit API would be storing the data on behalf of our app. But would this data be cleared if the user clears the app data? and Yes we do use History Api to pull the data.

Comment: Clearing the local data of your app wouldn't affect data that you've uploaded to Google Fit. I think users would expect to see historical data from your app if they install you app on another device, so using the History API to sync your local data with Google Fit does seem reasonable if you aren't maintaining your own server side storage separate from Google Fit.